# What are orbs of light?

Tags: destiny

Everytime you kill things with your super the killfeed says:

"[player] Generated # orbs of light"

They don't seem to be in my inventory anywhere or on the ground to pick up, what are they for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems to be something related to co-op gaming.

[From Destiny Wiki:](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Orb_of_Light)

> Orbs of Light are glowing balls of energy generated by other Guardians when they use their super abilities. Orbs can be picked up by any other player in the Fireteam, and provide a large boost to a player's super ability recharge meter.[1](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Orb_of_Light) The super ability recharge boost when the player picks up an Orb appears to be larger than the boost that players receive from kills, time, or other actions. Orbs of Light do not appear to serve any other function, and are a cooperative gameplay mechanic designed to encourage players to play in Fireteams and reward them for working together.

Comment: I recall picking some up and seeing large spikes in my super ability meter, so it may be anyone on your team can pick them up, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Orbs of light recharge your super abilities meter much faster than regular kills. Here is the Wiki article. http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Orb_of_Light

Comment: If your super is already maxed (or you haven't unlocked it yet), you won't be able to pick up the orbs. If some are on the ground and you're maxed, use your special!

Comment: Very true. Well said.